# Access component 's props in Svelte for Jest test

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, svelte, svelte-component

**Problem**: How to access the props for a svelte component using jest testing. For example if the svelte component is as below:

**ExampleComponent.svelte**

```
    <script>
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte'

    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher()
    export let booleanProp

    const toggle = () => {
        dispatch('toggle')
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss" src="./style.scss">
</style>

<button class:-closed="{booleanProp == false}" class="c-toggle" on:click={toggle}>
    <svg class="toggle-icon">
        {#if booleanProp}
            <use xlink:href="icons/some-icon.svg" />
        {:else}
            <use xlink:href="icons/some-other-icon.svg" />
        {/if}
    </svg>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties are the interface to the outer world. Mock it:

Example 1) mock the prop

```
    test("should render articles", () => {
  const booleanProp = " I am true";
  const { container, getByText } = render(ExampleComponent, {
    props: {
      articles: [
        {
          booleanProp
        }
      ]
    }
  });

  expect(container.querySelector("a").href).toBe(
    `http://localhost/${canonical_url}`
  );
  expect(getByText(myBool)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Good article: https://dev.to/jpblancodb/testing-svelte-components-with-jest-53h3

Example 2) mock the DOM

For testing a function behind the button.
The HTML code has the necessary elements to let the called function do its job:

```
   it('testFunctionModifiesDom', async () => {
        const documentHTML = 
            '<!doctype html><html><body>' +
            '<my-custom-element>' +
            '<input id="id0" value="true"/>' +. 
            '</my-custom-element>' +
            '</body></html>';
        document.body.innerHTML = documentHTML;

        const myCustomElement = document.querySelector('my-custom-element');

        let actual = myCustomElementsService.toggleMyBoolEffectsElement();

        expect(myCustomElement.getElementById('id0').value).toBe(false)
    })
```

Example 3) mock the component.

To check if a button click has an action using @testing-library:

```
import {render, fireEvent} from '@testing-library/svelte'
import {jest} from "@jest/globals";

it('testMyCustomElement_awesomeAction', async () => {
    const config = {booleanProp: true};
    const dom = render(MyCustomElement, config);

    const toggleButton = dom.getByLabelText('toggle-boolean-prop');
    await fireEvent.click(toggleButton);


    expect(config.booleanProp).toBe(false);
})
```

To catch the element you need an aria-label to identify it:

```
<button aria-label="toggle-boolean-prop" class:-closed="{booleanProp == false}" class="c-toggle" on:click={toggle}>...</button>
```

Comment: So just like a simple test case would be that I have a svelte file in which i have a boolean prop which needs to be checked if the value toggles with every button click event. I'm updating my question now to give you a little more idea about the exact use case. Thanks for your response though. :)

Comment: This is not the behaviour of the prop. A special function should handle bussiness logic. This should be testet in a separate test, which tests if this function toggels a value.

Comment: I guess you want to test functionallity, not implementation.

Comment: That is correct. I've seen the example which you posted but as you see, my example svelte file is a little different. Is there a possible way to check or mock the functionality of the boolean prop with a fireEvent from the button click?

Comment: I think you are looking for example 3 with the testing-library.